# Does the damage from Supernatural abilities bypass damage reduction?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction

The maneuver Obscuring Shadow Veil does 5d6 damage and is described as a supernatural ability. If I make an attack on a Devil with DR 10/good with a weapon and do 6 damage + 20 damage from the maneuver, does the Devil take 26, 20, or 16 points of damage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You would deal 26 damage if good; 20 damage if non-good.**

> [Damage Reduction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damagereduction)
>
> A creature with this special quality ignores damage from most weapons and natural attacks. **The creature takes normal damage from** energy attacks (even non-magical ones), spells, spell-like abilities, and **supernatural abilities**.

(emphasis: **bold**)

---

Obscurring Shadow Veil states:

> If it hits, your opponent takes normal melee damage *plus an extra 5d6 points of damage*.

What kind of extra damage are they taking?

> the fell energies of the Shadow Hand school.

It helps that they specifically mention "This maneuver is a supernatural ability.'

The maneuver would cause Normal Weapon Damage (that is subject to damage reduction) and Shadow Hand Damage (that is not subject to damage reduction).

Comment: Having reread the maneuver obscuring shadow veil, it's a better question than I originally thought. That is, *Is the maneuver's extra damage untyped damage (as is the case with a typical damage-dealing supernatural ability) **or** is the maneuver* itself *a supernatural ability that merely causes the weapon to deal extra damage of its usual type?* I think that probably needs addressing.